# How to call Google fonts only once

Tags: html, css, fonts

When checking my website with Google Page Speed I get the following error:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

One of the reasons has to do with the google fonts that are called in 2 different file. So I have the following:

```
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%7CMerienda+One%3A400&subset=latin&ver=1436185316
```

and the

```
fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans%3A400%2C700&ver=4.2.2
```

The latest is from the Cresta Social Plugin and as far as I know, it's not used anywhere else on the website. How can I change the Noto Sans font to Raleway so the server would only call the Raleway font?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: http://crocodillon.com/blog/non-blocking-web-fonts-using-localstorage

Answer (score 1):

I will show you start level..

Just got to google font and search your font.

https://www.google.com/fonts

see here

[image]

Now I have selected it weight and Now you will be check your page load.

[image]

Now finally how can we using currently google have provide three ways if you want go with javascript and then select javascript tab and select code and copy and paste with your code.

[image]

And important note internet connection is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know what to do with this. Where do I put this in Wordpress? My website is travelersuniverse.com if it helps you to have a look. Thanks!